# How to mock a service when validate request body and jump into class have @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I hava a controller like this:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> test(@RequestBody @Valid RestRequest request) {
    BodyRs BodyRs = service.setup(request.getBody());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(RestResponse.builder().body(BodyRs).build());
}
```

- When I call this controller with Request = '{}'(RestRequest not blank), it jump into:

  ```
  public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Autowired
  HolderService holderService;
  @Autowired
  LogService logService;

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotValid(WebRequest request) {


      RestResponseHeader responseHeader = RestResponseHeader.builder()
              .respCode("10")
              .respDesc(fieldError.getField() + " " + fieldError.getDefaultMessage())
              .build();

      RestResponse restResponse = RestResponse.builder()
              .header(responseHeader)
              .build();

      holderService.setRestResponse(restResponse);
      logService.log("100");
      return ResponseEntity.ok().body(restResponse);
  }
  ```
- How can I Mock LogService, because when I run unit test without starting MQ, it error at this line 'logService.log("100")'.

-I used to Mock it outside but when code jump into RestExceptionHandler, it is not a Mock object anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about unit test for `RestExceptionHandler`, you can either inject the mock, or (preferably in my mind) switch to use constructor autowiring and then it is easier to pass a mock in the constructor:

```
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  private HolderService holderService;
  private LogService logService;

  @Autowired
  public RestExceptionHandler(HolderService holderService, LogService logService) {
    this.holderService = holderService;
    this.logService = logService;
  }
...

}
```

If you are talking about integration test on your controller, you can use Springboot's `MockBean` annotation to create a mocked bean of your logger service

Comment: Thank you, I use MockBean then fixed issue.